# JPA that insert, update and delete at the same time

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA in a spring boot application to manage the database.
I have a case where the user can change in a list of items and I need in one database call to insert new tiems, update existing ones and delete the ones that are no longer needed by the user. Is there a way to achieve this?
I know that save can insert / update... but how about the delete option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  ended up using save for insert and update and handled the deletion management manually then called delete method to delete unwanted records